# Multiple X axis labels google charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts

How can I create multiple x Axis labels using the google charts API?

Im trying to create a bar graph right now with the main x axis labels as "products" and the individual bars relating to the products in question. However, I would like to segregate a set of 'n' products (data coming in from a database) by months.

Essentially I want a main X Axis label "product" and a dividing line between each set of products and a label underneath this set of bar graphs pertaining to the products grouping together each 'product set' by month

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me with this!!

Answer (score 2):

Sample double x-axis bar chart with google charts. Taken from their api documentation which can be found here:

[Double x-axis bar chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#dual-x-charts)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

      function drawStuff() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Galaxy', 'Distance', 'Brightness'],
          ['Canis Major Dwarf', 8000, 23.3],
          ['Sagittarius Dwarf', 24000, 4.5],
          ['Ursa Major II Dwarf', 30000, 14.3],
          ['Lg. Magellanic Cloud', 50000, 0.9],
          ['Bootes I', 60000, 13.1]
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 800,
          chart: {
            title: 'Nearby galaxies',
            subtitle: 'distance on the left, brightness on the right'
          },
          bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
          series: {
            0: { axis: 'distance' }, // Bind series 0 to an axis named 'distance'.
            1: { axis: 'brightness' } // Bind series 1 to an axis named 'brightness'.
          },
          axes: {
            x: {
              distance: {label: 'parsecs'}, // Bottom x-axis.
              brightness: {side: 'top', label: 'apparent magnitude'} // Top x-axis.
            }
          }
        };

      var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('dual_x_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="dual_x_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Not sure if that is exactly what you want to do, but if not let us know and we can modify this slightly.

Comment: Not quite.. I dont need a double x axis just double labels on it

Something like this
http://imageshack.com/a/img923/5359/JZy0Rq.png

Comment: I haven't seen that functionality in google chart.  Not sure if it will be feasible in your case, but would it be possible to just add html elements outside the chart area for the labels?  It's not uncommon to see people adding html outside of their chart that looks like it's part of the google chart framework.